# Branch Naming Policy

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-repos

Is it possible to create a custom branch naming policy that is enforced via Azure Devops?

For example, only allow the creation of branches that follow some sort of path/name pattern, like `/features/{user-name}/{story id}-branchname` ?

Comment: Enforcing a particular branch name format in a public repo might make sense, but part of the appeal of a tool like git is the ability to make as many branches as you want so that a you can experiment without worrying that you can't get back to a sane state. To restrict that is to unnecessarily handcuff your developers.

Answer (score 2):

> When you have many people collaborating in a repository, the number
> and names of branches can quickly get out of control. Hierarchical
> branch folders is an effective way to tame the chaos. Azure DevOps
> Services, TFS, and Visual Studio treat / as a folder separator and
> will automatically collapse folders by default. This way, you don't
> have to wade through every single branch to find the one you're
> looking for. You don't have to rely on everyone to get it right,
> either. Azure Repos and TFS can enforce the correct use of branch
> folders.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/require-branch-folders?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser

Hopefully this is a step in the right direction!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).